# How to do the FizzBuzz problem using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, fizzbuzz

I was just learning about for loops and stuff and successfully did a FizzBuzz problem, my current code is like so:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
  if ($i % 15 == 0) {
    echo 'FizzBuzz<br>';
  } elseif ($i % 3 == 0) {
    echo 'Fizz<br>';
  } elseif ($i % 5 == 0) {
    echo 'Buzz<br>';
  } else {
    echo $i . '<br>';
  }
}

?>
```

Now I was just wondering what if we have a MySQL table containing 100 rows that have numbers from 1 - 100 inside of them.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers_from_one_to_hundred (
  id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  numbers INT(11) NOT NULL
);
```

Now I want to do the FizzBuzz problem with PHP and MySQLi linked with the numbers_from_one_to_hundred.

By the way, I didn't use any prepared statements and stuff in this one because I am bad at them and this is just a pet project so no security worries.

So I did something like this that did not end up working:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `numbers_from_one_to_hundred`";

$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
  $numbers = $row['numbers'];
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $numbers; $i++) {
    if ($i % 15 == 0) {
      echo 'FizzBuzz<br>';
    } elseif ($i % 3 == 0) {
      echo 'Fizz<br>';
    } elseif ($i % 5 == 0) {
      echo 'Buzz<br>';
    } else {
      echo $i . '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with this? It really doesn't output anything at all but when I try print_r with the results it does seem to give the results so something is probably wrong with my logic am I doing it all completely wrong? Can someone explain to me how this should be done?

Comment: If you expect your rows to be sorted, then you need to add 'order by numbers' to your query.  Do you need to cast your numbers to an int when you assign it?  "It really doesn't output anything at all" is not helpful.  At least give us the print_r output then.

Comment: @AllanWind Ok I'll add the print_r output, and yes I do want to my rows to be sorted I'll add that to my query right away, and no I don't necessarily need to cast them to an int or do I? sorry for being a bit rubbish I am just a beginner.

Comment: @AllanWind here is the print_r output 
`mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 2 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 99 [type] => 0 )`

Comment: Oh @AllanWind thanks sorting it by using ORDER BY keyword actually worked thanks for the help I am gonna answer my questions myself I suppose so that others can get helped by it as well

Comment: Also, you don't need  both the id and numbers column.  Either would do.  ProTip use <table>_id for your primary key.  This makes your life easier when you when you want to joint multiple tables.  Also in code, specify the columns rather than '*'.

Comment: It seems to me that if you have the 'while' then you don't need the 'for'

Comment: @Strawberry maybe you got a bit wrong there the while loop iterates through the results of the MySQL query It doesn't have anything to do with the fizzBuzz code itself. Or maybe you have a better way in mind then kindly please let me know :)

Comment: I don't think so. You're iterating through a while result that you know contains integers from (0/1) to 100, so your for loop (which does exactly the same thing) is redundant. $i is unnecessary. $numbers is the same value (on an ordered result)

Comment: @Strawberry hmmm maybe you are right perhaps the code can be improved the while loop does seem useless, thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, I'd keep the while and lose the for

Comment: @Strawberry hmm I see, why do you prefer the while over the for tho?

Comment: Because I can't remember how to parse a result using for. Happy new year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `order by numbers` to your query so rows are returned sorted.